# BLE Shield v2.1

Tags: bluetooth, android

I have an Arduino Mega 2560 and a BLE Shield v 2.1 from RedBearLab. When I try to connect it through Bluetooth from my laptop to 'BLE Shield', it says 'Connected!'. When I try from a Windows phone, it also says 'Connected'.

But when I try to connect from an Android device, it gives me an error: 'pairing rejected by BLE shield' or 'couldn't pair with BLE Shield because of an incorrect PIN or passkey'.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the problem is an incorrect PIN or passkey.

I've read from manuals for some gadgets that some devices/phones automatically try the PIN 0000 and some don't.  I have never seen my Windows phone ask for a PIN when the device hasn't got one set, so I'm guessing that Windows automatically tries 0000 and Android doesn't.  Is there a  setting on Android that will let you enter the pin (which is probably 0000) ?

Comment: Also, sometimes the pin is 1234 on default and can be changed through AT commands